# How to cast EventHandler<T> to EventHandler<EventArgs>?

Tags: c#, casting, event-handling

I'm creating a centralized event aggregator that keeps a registry that accepts EventHandler delegates. The aggregator class itself is not generic, but the register method is:

```
public void RegisterHandler<T>(EventHandler<T> handler) where T : EventArgs
{
    Debug.Assert(handler != null);
    if (handler != null)
    {
        if (this._eventRegistry != null)
        {
            this._eventRegistry.AddValue(typeof(T), handler);
        }
        else { /* Do nothing. */ }
    }
    else 
    { 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(ReflectionUtilities.GetVariableName(() => handler)); 
    }
}
```

The aim is to allow registry of any type that derives from EventArgs. But the registry (a type of Dictionary) accepts EventHandler of type EventArgs and not EventHandler of type T where T is EventArgs.

The line

```
this._eventRegistry.AddValue(typeof(T), handler);
```

will not compile because it says it has some invalid arguments (specifically 'handler'). If I change that argument to

```
this._eventRegistry.AddValue(typeof(T), handler as EventHandler<EventArgs>);
```

then the code compiles but the argument 'handler' has a null value.

Similarly, if I do this:

```
EventHandler<EventArgs> eventHandler = handler as EventHandler<EventArgs>;
```

then 'eventHandler' is null.

If I know that T is constrained to be type or subtype of EventArgs, how can I cast

```
EventHandler<T>
```

to

```
EventHandler<EventArgs>
```

?

Comment: `EventHandler<T>` is invariant on `T`.  The closest you can get for delegates is the `Delegate` class.  Make your dictionary a mapping from types to delegates (or some wrapper).

Comment: Why not RegisterHandler(EventArgs) instead of the generic method?

Comment: @devundef Do you mean `RegisterHandler(EventHandler<EventArgs>)`? The method needs a reference to a method so it can be called later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cast an `EventHandler<T>` to an `EventHandler<EventArgs>`. A somewhat ugly but simple workaround, is to change this line of your code:

```
this._eventRegistry.AddValue(typeof(T), handler);
```

to

```
this._eventRegistry.AddValue(typeof(T), (sender, evt) => handler(sender, (T)evt));
```

Comment: The code you've created will *compile*, but it'll just fail at runtime, for exactly the reason it doesn't let you cast the handlers in the first place (treating one as the other simply isn't an appropriate conversion).

Comment: @Servy I am assuming that the implemented `EventRegistry` class will only invoke the handler if the event is actually of type `T`.

Comment: @Alex Just an update in case you're interested. The same thing can be done with a regular dictionary that takes a `System.MulticastDelegate` as its value. Then, since the methods accept only parameters of a particular type, these can be casted back to the generic type without fail.